# Преобразовать \u0412\u0437... строку Unicode в читаемый вид python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Всем привет. Читаю xml файл, в атрибуте текст:

```
"DESC: &quot;\u0412\u0437\u043D\u043E\u0441&quot;&#xA;"
```

который читается в питон как:

```
'DESC: "\\u0412\\u0437\\u043D\\u043E\\u0441"\n'
```

Вопрос: как преобразовать строку в читаемый вид?
Xml файл читаю с помощью модуля **xml.etree.ElementTree**

---

XML получаю следующим образом и читаю из него данные (Python 3.4), кратко:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as XML
response = requests.request( "GET"
                           , self.ApiUrl
                           , headers = self.Headers
                           , params = self.QueryString)
root_xml = XML.fromstring(response.text)
for xml_tag in root_xml:
  text = xml_tag.text
```

Так вот `print(text)` полчаю `'DESC: "\\u0412\\u0437\\u043D\\u043E\\u0441"\n'`

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгий ответ. Вечером добавлю пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перекодируйте текст с помощью кодировки 'unicode_escape' (для Python 3.x, в Python 2.x была кодировка 'string_escape', но с ней не пробовал).

```
import codecs

s = 'DESC: "\\u0412\\u0437\\u043D\\u043E\\u0441"\n'
text = codecs.decode(s, 'unicode_escape')
print(text)
```

Результат:
    DESC: "Взнос"

Comment: А у меня ошибка `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-11: ordinal not in range(128)` python 3.4.2

Comment: Странно. Сейчас под рукой нет Python 3.4, попробовал в разных Python 3.5, в том числе и онлайновом - https://repl.it/E8WA/0

Comment: В Python 3.5.2 работает. Но у меня 3.4 ^(