# как перевести текстовый unicode в настоящий

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть текст `"\u0430"`, приходит из внешнего источника в таком виде. Как его привести к виду `u'\0430'` (при `print` выведет `a`)?

```
t = "\u0430"
print u'{}'.format(t)
# \u0430
print unicode(t)
# u'\\u0430'
```

А хочется как здесь:

```
print u'\u0430'
# a
```

Comment: У вас странный источник. Вы случайно не пытаетесь парсить json регулярками или какими-то ещё извращениями? Расскажите лучше про источник

Comment: связанный вопрос [Преобразовать \u0412\u0437... строку Unicode в читаемый вид python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596217/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
print t.decode(encoding="unicode_escape")
```

Результат:

```
>>> t = "\u0430"
>>> print t.decode(encoding="unicode_escape")
а
```